# no classes are being updated to body tag on page load in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, frontend, tags

every thing was working fine and suddenly the alignment of whole page changed on inspecting i found that the classes are not being updated in body tag in UAT on home page the body tag is

```
<body data-container="body" id="html-body" class="cms-home cms-page-2 cms-index-index page-layout-1column" aria-busy="false">
```

but in current env its showing like
`<body>` only

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's module mailchimp
https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/commit/a80240f9a6abdf6a4c9979070a2965c27eeba774
script tag not closed and body classes removed